# Ruby looping through a specific array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a way to loop through a specific array?
For example, `user.org_names` returns:

```
["NEW", "Gold", "HEALTH SPRING"] ["Text Illinois"] ["Star Gold"] ["NEW", "Star Gold"] ["NEW", "Star Gold", "HEALTH SPRING"] ["Star Gold"] ["Star Gold"] ["Text Illinois", "Star Text", "Star Gold"] ["Text Illinois", "HEALTH SPRING"] ["NEW", "Star Gold", "Star Text"]
```

Now, I want to loop only through the fourth array `["NEW", "Star Gold"]`.

Is that a possibility in Ruby? I couldn't find such a feature.

Comment: `user.org_names[3]` will return the 4th element of the array

Comment: The return value is not valid ruby syntax: if this is a nested array, the enclosing brackets and the commas between the inner arrays are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the basic array notation `[]` with the index as argument to get the value:

```
user.org_names[3] # get the 4th element of the array returned
                  # returns nil if does not exists
```

In your case, if you want to loop on the 4th element:

```
fourth_element = user.org_names[3]
fourth_element.each do |element|
  # use element
end if fourth_element.present?
```

This behaves the same as:

```
fourth_element = user.org_names[3]
if fourth_element.present?
  fourth_element.each do |element|
    # use element
  end
end
```

---

`if` after the `end`

```
1.9.3p489 :006 > [1,2,3].each do |n|
1.9.3p489 :007 >   puts n
1.9.3p489 :008?> end if false
 => nil
```

Basically the same as doing:

```
[1,2,3].each{ |n| puts n } if false
```

But using a `do/end` syntax and multi-line

Answer (score 0):

You can do that this way

```
user.org_names[3].each do |element|
  puts element
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is an array of arrays, maybe you could get the fourth element (`user.org_names[3]`) of the array and loop through it like this:

```
<% i = 0 %>
<% user.org_names[3].each do |a| %>
    <% a[i] %>
    <% i+=1 %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This does not increment `i`, use `i += 1`